# What information is available for the town Fallcrest?

Tags: dnd-4e, campaign-development

My next campaign will have some town adventures.  I'm looking at the Fallcrest town detailed in the **Dungeon Master's Guide**.

Before I get too far into it, I'd like to know if the town has been featured in other products.  Particularly if there is significant background information available.

Comment: Like the rest of the Points of Light setting, Fallcrest is a template for you to fill in with whatever your group needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fallcrest is also featured in the current season of Keep on the Borderlands (D&D Encounters Season 3). There's a big collection of regional information available here:

http://community.wizards.com/dungeonsanddragons/go/thread/view/91301/25890389/DM_Tools_for_Season_3?pg=1

Answer (score 5):

There are some nice fan drawn maps (unofficial) of Fallcrest over at [D&D Doodle](http://dandddoodles.blogspot.com/2009/07/fallcrest-rough-iii.html)

They are based off of the DMG material, and include a player's version and a DM's version.

Comment: D&D Doodle is an awesome resource I'd never heard of before - great tip, Simon!